# Get list of method from controller name that is in string format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following function to return the selectlist of the action name from controller name of string type:

```
public ActionResult get_all_action(string controllername)
        {
            Type t = Type.GetType(controllername);
            MethodInfo[] mi = t.GetMethods();

            List<SelectListItem> action = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (MethodInfo m in mi)
            {
                if (m.IsPublic)
                    if (typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(m.ReturnParameter.ParameterType))
                    {
                        action.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = m.Name, Text = m.Name });
                    }
            }

            var List = new SelectList(action, "Value", "Text");

            return Json(List, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The parameter controllername of get_all_action() is passed as for example "AccountController". But the exception is thrown at

```
MethodInfo[] mi = t.GetMethods();
```

as:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"AccountController"` is not a full type name; it needs to be something like `"YourApp.Whatever.AccountController"` for `GetType()` to find it. It is also worth making it explicit which assembly it is in, for example:

```
var thisType = GetType();
Type t = thisType.Assembly.GetType(
    thisType.Namespace + "." + controllerName);
```

(which assumes we mean the same assembly / namespace)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `Type.GetType` returns `null`, as it can't find class for specified name `AccountController`. You should specify the full name with namespace. Also, if your controller class is not from executing assembly, you must use qualified assembly name (like

```
TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.AccountController, MyAssembly
```

).

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the [**assembly-qualified name**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) to `Type.GetType(controllername)`